# Visual Studio - Make Recover Files Dialogue go away

Tags: visual-studio

The Dialogue says

> Microsoft Visual Studio was automatically closed during the installation of an update.  Microsoft Visual Studio can try to recover the following information for you.

And then there are the same two files listed.

I have done just about everything possible to make this go away.  I have recovered.  I have "Do Not Recover"   I have done it with the check boxes checked and unchecked.  I have shut down completely and reloaded.

This Dialogue still appears every time I open Visual Studio.  Please make it stop.

Comment: What are those two files?

Comment: Just .cs files from a project

Comment: Does it happen for just that one solution, and do the files exist at the location indicated in the error message? Anyway, like with other state corruptions, try deleting the `.vs` directory under the solution root (note: that will lose some history and options).